# adding swipe gesture to view controllers on storyboard not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am pretty new to this so i was following this tutorial.

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u1-DGiUhXU
```

I have 4 view controllers with images etc. And i have done exactly as per this video. My problem is, if i tap, drag do anything nothing happens. I am just stuck at main screen. I have tried changing `push` to `model` but it don't work either.

Any Ideas?

Comment: @jonkroll there is no code in storyboards mate

Comment: hello,how u solved this issue?me too followed the tutorial in the video and the swipe is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set your imageViews UserInteractionEnabled = YES to enable touches cause it is =NO by default. Just solved similar problem this way.

EDIT: I've just repeated the actions described in video and everything works fine! You really should follow the video guide carefuly!
P.S. The swipe gesture should be a quick move from the left side of screen to the right.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Intercept touches? What kind of touches ?

Comment: i have 3 controllers, i just want to swipe. move my pointer from left to right i want to change views. Exactly like the video. Strangly its not working.

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same tutorial and I had the same problem and i solved it as follows:

When dragging the Swipe Gesture Recognizer u MUST drag it into the view itself(where the background color apears).
When it wasnt working for me i was dragging it to the Black bar on the bottom.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. You are only allow to drag it into the view